# How to catch & append a textbox value to a URL in this PHP code?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I managed to get my API lyrics code working. All I'm facing is a small problem: When a user enters a song name in a textbox and clicks the submit button, I catch the value via getElementById, and then how do I append it with the URL below?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
     //Catches the value of the Submit button: 
     $submit = isset($_POST['submit']);
     if($submit) {
?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var val1 = document.getElementById('val').value;
     </script>
<?php
    /* The below $res contains the URL where I wanna append the caught value. 
       Eg: http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=Nothing Else Matters(Or 
       what the user searches for)&for=trackname&agent=agent
    */
      $res = file_get_contents("http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q='+val1+' &for=trackname&agent=agent");
?>
<html>
   <form method="post" action="">
      Enter value: <input type="text" name="value" id="val" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
   </form>
</html>
```

Could you please correct me as to where I'm making a mistake in this piece of code, highly appreciate all help in this forum! :)

Comment: that wouldn't work .. why don't you just submit the form to the page and do `...?q=" . urlencode($_POST['value']) . "&for...`;

Comment: @scibuff: I was trying to do it in a single page only, tried it via javascript function too, but thought of doing this way.. I'll try the way you suggested too :). Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: then the option is to use Ajax to fetch the content and write it back to the html page

Comment: @scibuf: Yea, none of the below methods were working, I finally did it via passing the parameters across another page, would implement that only for now :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, what you need to do is:

```
<?php
     //Catches the value of the Submit button: 
     $submit = isset($_POST['submit']);
     if($submit) {
     $val1 = $_POST['val'];    // TO store form passed value in "PHP" variable.
    /* The below $res contains the URL where I wanna append the caught value. 
       Eg: http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=Nothing Else Matters(Or 
       what the user searches for)&for=trackname&agent=agent
    */
      $res = file_get_contents("http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=' . urlencode($val1) . ' &for=trackname&agent=agent");
   }   // This is to end the "if" statement
?>
```

and then change the form input field to:

```
      Enter value: <input type="text" name="val" id="val" /><br/>
```

I am not sure if POST accepts `id` values too!

Comment: I dont know why this code isnt working, though yes this is what I want.. Its always returning error codes in the results from the API, while when I tested it for a particular song like the one I wrote in my post, it was returning the  results normally..

Answer (score -1):

Remove the javascript it's unnecessary. *PHP runs at the **server***. *Javascript at the **client***.

Then change your PHP code to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $res = file_get_contents("http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=". $_POST['value'] ." &for=trackname&agent=agent");
}
```